# How to persist column index of a WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to persist the index value of each column of my own datagrid but I don't know how to do it. Looks like the index can only be set thru the order of addition of the columns on the xaml code.

Any help will be great, thanks.

Comment: dataGrid.Columns gives you a collection of columns ordered by index, doesn't that suffice?

Comment: If I change the order of the collection the order of the column in the UI  changes?

Comment: A change on the collection does not change the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, columns have a DisplayIndex property that I can bind to my column ViewModel.